# hook_node_access() returning NODE_ACCESS_DENY is ignored

Tags: 7, nodes

I am trying to block the current user from performing any action (view, update, delete) on a node. The user should only be able to view, update, delete the node being displayed if he is the owner of the node, or the owner of the node is a subuser of his (I am using the *Subuser* module).

The function below returns the correct value for the various tests I performed, but when the function returns NODE_ACCESS_DENY, the access isn't denied. The user can still see the node.

Is there something I am missing?

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  if (is_object($node)) {
    if ($node->type == 'my_content_type') {
      // Determine the current uid and, if the user doesn't have the right role, deny the access
      if (is_array($account->roles) && in_array('vip', $account->roles)) {
        $current_uid  = $account->uid;
      } elseif ( is_array($account->roles) && 
                !in_array('administrator', $account->roles)) {
        return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
      } else {
        return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
      }

      // Determine the node owner.
      $node_owner = $node->uid;

      // If the node owner is the same as the current user, allow to view the node
      if ($current_uid == $node_owner) {
        return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
      }

      // If not, check if the node owner is a subuser of the current vip user
      $node_owner_profile = user_load($node_owner);
      if (isset($node_owner_profile->field_parent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
        if ($node_owner_profile->field_parent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == $current_uid) {
          return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
        } else {
          return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
        }
      } else {
        return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
      }
    }
  }

  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Comment: Install the Devel module, and add the node access blocks to your main content area (forget exactly what they are called).  What do they say?  Also keep in mind that hook_node_access() isn't called for everything.  The grant system is better, in general, for ACL.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the code you are showing: A variable is initialized inside a `if()` control block, but it is used outside that block.
`$current_uid` is initialized from the following code.

```php
if (is_array($account->roles) && in_array('vip', $account->roles)) {
  $current_uid  = $account->uid;
}
```

It is then used from the following code.

```php
// If the node owner is the same as the current user, allow to view the node
if ($current_uid == $node_owner) {
  return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
}
```

That code only works if the account object passed to the hook has the *vip* role, or if the node has been created from the anonymous user (whose ID is 0). Differently, `$current_uid` will be set to `NULL`.

Also, the code I shown in the second snippet does not do what the comment says: It allows the logged-in user to view, edit, update, and delete the node; it does not just allow the logged-in user to view the node.
The only operation that code is not allowing is creating a node of that content type, since in that case Drupal would pass the content type string in `$node` and the code is checking `$node` is an object.

To achieve what the comment is describing, the correct code is the following one.

```php
if ($current_uid == $node_owner && $op == 'view') {
  return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
}
```

I would rather use the following code.

```php
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  if (is_object($node)) {
    if ($type == 'my_content_type') {
      $current_uid = $account->uid;
      $node_owner = $node->uid;
      if (is_array($account->roles)) {
        if (!in_array('vip', $account->roles) && !in_array('administrator', $account->roles)) {
          return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
        }
        elseif (in_array('administrator', $account->roles)) {
          return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
        }
      }
      else {
        return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
      }

      if ($current_uid == $node_owner && $op == 'view') {
        return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
      }

      $node_owner_profile = user_load($node_owner);
      if (isset($node_owner_profile->field_parent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
        if ($node_owner_profile->field_parent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == $current_uid) {
          return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
        } else {
          return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
        }
      } else {
        return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
      }
    }
  }

  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Keep in mind that, when the logged-in user has the *bypass node access* permission, `hook_node_access()` implementations are not invoked.
`hook_node_access()` implementations are also not invoked for page listing nodes, for example RSS feeds, or the default front page whose path is *node*.
Testing whether the value returned by a `hook_node_access()` implementation is respected by using an account with *bypass node access* permission or accessing the default front page does not have the expected result, especially in the case the expected result is that the operation is not allowed.

Instead of checking the roles of the user account, I would rather check if the user has a specific permission. `hook_node_access()` implementations are allowed to use `user_permission()`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However, I've made the suggested changes, without any positive result. I've put `drupal_set_message()` messages before each return statement in order to see what the function returns. In all test cases the returned value was correct. But even when `NODE_ACCESS_DENY` was returned, the user could still see the node. I haven't granted _bypass content access control_ permission to any role except _administrator_. I haven't implemented `hook_node_access` anywhere else on my website. Is it possible that another module could override my code?

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is in fact a workaround. I have adapted the code as necessary and used it in template_preprocess_node The code is adding a new variable to the $variables array - called $access_allowed.

In node--content-type.tpl.php, I check that variable. If TRUE, I display the node. Otherwise, I redirect to the 403 page.

I know it's not as elegant as the solution using hook_node_access, but, for now, it works for me. If anyone finds a better solution, it would be great!

Thanks